# Questions related to total set of linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces, weak-topology

Following questions are from *Linear Operators* edited by **Nelson Dunford** and **Jacob T. Schwartz**, Chapter V.7, Problem 5 and Problem 7.

Let $X$ be a topological vector space (call its topology $\tau$). Given a set $\Gamma$ of linear functionals defined on $X$ (some element in $\Gamma$ could be unbounded), call $\Gamma$ total iff we have $[f(x) = 0\,\forall\,f \in \Gamma]\,\Leftrightarrow\,[x = 0]$. Use $\tau_{\gamma}$ to denote the weak topology generated by elements in $\Gamma$ and then show:

1. Let $A$ be a $\tau_{\gamma}$ open subset. If there exists $r > 0$ and a $\tau$-open neighborhood of $\vec{0}$, say $V$ such that $r A \subseteq V$ (**we call this $\tau$-bounded**), then $X$ is finite dimensional
2. If $\Gamma$ is a vector space, show that a set $S \subseteq X$ is $\tau_{\gamma}$ bounded iff $f(S)$ is bounded for all $f \in \Gamma$.

Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: The condition in (1) is trivial because we can always choose $V=X$.

Answer (score 0):

2)) $(\Rightarrow)$ Let $f\in\Gamma$ be any functional. Then $V=\{x\in X: |f(x)|<1\}$ is a $\tau_\gamma$ neighborhood of the zero of $X$. Thus there exists a positive number $M$ such that $MV\supset S$. It follows $|f(x)|\le M$ for each $x\in S$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $V\in\tau_\gamma$ be any neighborhood of the zero. There exists a finite subset $F$ of $\Gamma$ such that $V\supset \{x\in X: |f(x)|\le 1\mbox{ for each }f\in F\}$. We have  $M=\sup_{f\in F\, x\in S} |f(x)|<\infty$ and $S\subset MV$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. In your proof to ($\Rightarrow$) direction, I am bit confused how do you know the set $\{x \in X\,\vert\,\vert\,f(x)\,\vert < 1\}$ is in $\tau_{\gamma}$. Is an open set we know in $\tau_{\gamma}$ always an union of sets of the form $\{x \in X\,\vert\,f(x)\,\vert < 1\,\forall\,f \in F\}$ where $F \subseteq \Gamma$ is finite?

Comment: @SanaeKochiya I understood that the topology $\tau_\gamma$ has a base at each point $x\in X$ consisting of sets of form $\{y\in X: |f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon \mbox{ for all }f\in F\}$, where $F$ is any finite subset of $\Gamma$ and $\varepsilon>0$ be any number. This implies that $V$ is a $\tau_\gamma$  neighborhood of the zero of $X$.

Comment: My bad ... Now I saw your $f \in \Gamma$ is fixed before defining $V$. I completely misunderstood the question and thought it wants $f(S)$ uniformly bounded for all $f \in \Gamma$.